# Git repository backup (mirror) solution for Open Source Software projects

Tags: open-source, backup, git, version-control, github

I'm looking for a service which is similar to GitHub to store my Open Source projects. Ideally, the following functionality should be supported:

1. Automatic cloning of the whole repository from GitHub (e.g. every day)
2. Ability to use as a normal git repo but without a write access (the GitHub repositories serve as master repositories)

The goal is to have more diversification and store the code on multiple services, so that if GitHub repositories go down, all of the data will still be safe and can be recovered.

Comment: You could have your own NAS box with your GIT archive on it.

Comment: Obviously, but I'm looking for a cloud solution similar to GitHub. So that it would be easier to start/maintain.

As for the self-hosted solution, what tool would you recommend for that, if there is an option? Looking for something off-the-shelf

Comment: You can set up pretty much any git service to be in sync with help of GitHub actions. Here's an example with GitLab: https://dev.to/brunorobert/github-and-gitlab-sync-44mn

Comment: Great article, thanks. Actually I used GitLab for this before, but they have disabled that feature for non-premium users. I'll take a look.